# Reading and Evaluating an Iterated Integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I'm sorry if this is a rather elementary question, but I'm a bit confused on the computation of a particular iterated integral. Let $\mu_1$ be the counting measure on $\mathbb{R}$, and let $\mu_2$ simply be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. If $E = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: 0 \leq x = y \leq 1\}$, let $f(x,y) = 1_E(x,y)$.
I am then asked to compute the following iterated integral:

$$\int_\mathbb{R} d\mu_2(x) \int_\mathbb{R} f(x,y) d\mu_1(y)$$

As far as I was aware, this was just another way of writing $$\int_\mathbb{R} \left( \int_\mathbb{R} f(x,y) d\mu_1(y) \right) d\mu_2(x)$$

Observing that $f(x,y) = 1_{S(E,x)}(y)$ where $S(E,x) = \{y \in \mathbb{R}: (x,y) \in E\}$, I compute the inner integral as follows:
$$\int_\mathbb{R} f(x,y) d\mu_1(y) = \int_\mathbb{R} 1_{S(E,x)}(y) d\mu_1(y) = \int_{S(E,x)} d\mu_1(y) = \mu_1(S(E,x)) \underbrace{=}_{\text{$S(E,x)$ is a singleton}} 1$$

Since the inner integral is $1$, then for the iterated integral we have $$\int_\mathbb{R} \left( \int_\mathbb{R} f(x,y) d\mu_1(y) \right) d\mu_2(x) = \int_\mathbb{R} d\mu_2(x) = \mu_2(\mathbb{R}) = \infty$$

However, I have been informed that this iterated integral was supposed to evaluate to just $1$. Could anyone shed light on this? What have I failed to account for, or what have I computed incorrectly? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The iterated integrals are not in general equal. Have you studied Fubini's theorem? Most likely what is going on here is that $f$ is not $\mu_1\times\mu_2$-integrable, so the order of integration cannot be interchanged.

Comment: I wasn't aware that I had switched the order of integration. I thought $$\int_\mathbb{R} d\mu_2(x) \int_\mathbb{R} f d\mu_1 := \int_\mathbb{R} \left( \int_\mathbb{R} f d\mu_1 \right) d\mu_2$$ and I was just trying to compute $ \int_\mathbb{R} \left( \int_\mathbb{R} f d\mu_1 \right) d\mu_2$. I found $ \int_\mathbb{R} \left( \int_\mathbb{R} f d\mu_1 \right) d\mu_2 = \infty$, but I was informed $ \int_\mathbb{R} \left( \int_\mathbb{R} f d\mu_1 \right) d\mu_2 = 1$ which is what I was confused about.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I misread what you wrote. In general that is what would cause such a discrepancy. My next thought would be that the result of the integral with respect to counting measure is not supposed to be a constant, because the integral of any constant function over $\mathbb R$ would be infinite. Rather it should be something like $\mathsf 1_{[0,1]}(x)$, which would integrate to $1$.

Comment: It's not the order of integrals that I find confusing.  It is "$0\le x= y\le 1$".  Clearly that means that both x and y lie between 0 and 1.  But what does that "x= y" mean?  I suppose that could mean the line y= x from x= 0 to x= 1 but that is one-dimensional and it makes no sense to do a double integral over a one-dimensional set.  It would make more sense to integrate over $0\le x \le y \le 1$.  That would be the two dimensional triangle with vertices (0, 0), (1, 0), and (1, 1).  You appear to be saying that $d\mu_1= dx$ and $d\mu_2= dy$. Is that correct?